# Python kivy and Linux Mint compatibility issue

Tags: python, linux, kivy, linux-mint

I have several programs written in python and kivy language, all of them written in windows environment and working properly. When I tried to run them in Linux Mint, i get a `"UnicodeDecodeError"`. This happens only to the programs that `import kivy` and it's modules, while all my other python programs work fine. So i wrote a simple kivy program in Linux Mint to see if there is a problem with being written in Win10 and still I get the same error. I've looked it up and saw that others too have similar issues but not the same so i couldn't find an answer to fit my needs.

my releases are: Python 3.4.0 | Kivy 1.9.1 | Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64bit

Here's my program written in Linux Mint environment:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class mylabel(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Linux Mint!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylabel().run()
```

And here's the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mintkivy.py", line 9, in <module>
     mylabel().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 451, in runTouchApp
     p = provider(key, args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/probesysfs.py", line 155, in __new__
     instance.__init__(device, args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/probesysfs.py", line 192, in __init__
     self.probe()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/probesysfs.py", line 213, in probe
     device.name, device.device))
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/probesysfs.py", line 80, in name
     return read_line(path)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/probesysfs.py", line 145, in read_line
     return f.readline().strip()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
     return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

p.s. I have installed kivy in Linux and after i got the problem i added it in the PyCharm compiler too, and they both produce the same error.

I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to Mint 18 and installing kivy by apt. I had some problems with py3 and Mint 17.2, that solved it.

Comment: @ jligeza I will try this, thank you!